# Powerdesigner domain auto_increment

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerdesigner

I'm building a database for a website, 
using PowerDesigner.
I'm using domains for the ID's and want an ID to be auto_increment.
Is there a way to get the DDL/CREATE script with auto_increment in it, using Microsoft SQL server 2014? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an `Identity` property on my `Domain`.
[image]

You can also change the selected columns in the list to see this property.
[image]